# Put an iframe on the right

Tags: html, iframe, width

So I want to make an iframe for a page that would display a selection of teas and herbal teas, and I want the options on the left in another iframe. Though, it's been so long I haventdone that and I oly didit with DreamWeaver before (I'm unexperienced so I followed a teacher's tutorial), so the software generated most of the code, really. Could anyone help me please? Right now, here's the iframe's code along with the banner:

```
    <div class="container">
        <img src="images/bannersite.png" alt="Banner" style="width:100%;">
        
        <div class="bigtxt" style="left: 100px; top: 70px; position: absolute;">
            <span style="color: #B3D1B3;">Ma</span><span style="color: #404040;">Thé</span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <iframe src="accueil.html" style="width: 99.8%;">
    </iframe>
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: website with unwanted stuff]

As you can see, there's a scrolling bar below, and that's because for some reason theiframe decided it would continue on the left of the banner's right end, and I don't want that. I want the iframe and the banner to both fit the whole screen.

Here's what I would like to do but have no clue how:

[image: what I wanna do]

Thanks for anyone who's willing to help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I have a posted a solution that includes CSS code instead of inline CSS. It is the same but it uses `classes` instead of inline `style=""`. Please review the comments, play with the codepen and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Also, there should be no scrollbar in the bottom using the code I provided. If however, there still is, try adding this code to the css:   `body{overflow-x:hidden}`

Answer (score 3):

Please take a note, iframes are not good for SEO. It's much better to use java script or jquery driven pieces of code. Google and others are not trustibg to iframe, making yuor website rating a lot decrese.

Comment: thanks for sharing that, I was actually not aware of that!

Comment: Really? I have no idea how to do that, though. any tutorial online if you have one please? thanks

Comment: Please use this one: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_website.asp

Comment: Read about ajax, Jquery, css3, html5 technologies. If you want website that will be nice and under your full control of your wishes, so you have to learn them. At least you have to understand the princeps of how to use them in the right and efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this codepen, I think it does what you are looking for.

https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/mdPGzdm

I edited your code a bit and please read the comments I made for you to better understand the new lines of code. There is a HTML code and a CSS code that applies to it, with classes (they begin with a ".")

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"> <!-- this is the container for the picture and the "MaThé" text -->
        <img src="https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/sunflower_background_03_hd_picture_165827.jpg" alt="Banner">
        <div class="bigtxt" style="left: 100px; top: 70px; position: absolute;">
            <span style="color: #B3D1B3;">Ma</span>
            <span style="color: #404040;">Thé</span>
        </div>
</div> <!-- top header container closes here -->

<div class="flex-container"> <!-- this is the container for the sidebar and the iframe on the right -->
  <div class="sidebar">
    <button>Button</button>
    <button>Button</button> 
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sJIjIMMIoSw" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**CSS**

```
.container img {
  width:100%;max-height:250px;
}

.bigtxt {
  font-size:50px;
}

.flex-container { /* the display attribute set to flex creates a "flexbox" display, please see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox */
  display:flex;width:100%;
}

.sidebar { /* this container is also set to flex, but here we change the flex-direction to column for the buttons to display in a column */
  display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:300px;justify-content:center;width:30%;align-items:center; /* giving a width of 30% to the sidebar, it will fill 30% of the available space, which is 100% of the window width as defined above */ /* by setting align-items and justify-content to "center" the buttons place themselves in the middle of the sidebar */
}

.sidebar button {
  margin:30px 0;max-width:100px; /* giving a bottom and a top margin ofo 30px to the buttons to space them apart */
}

iframe {
  width:70%; /* here we simply set the width of the iframe to the remaining space which is 70% of the 100% width of the .flexbox container */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me a lot. The margin of 30 px; fro buttons isn't displaying though. What does 30px 0; with that "0" mean y the way? I'venever used a 0 after my margin values.

Do you happen to know how to write a code for the buttons (ex.one button would be "tea" and it would show my page tea.html in the iframe etc.)?

Comment: Here's the result, oddly:

https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/38/kf4m.png

Comment: @manouna glad it helped. `margin:30px 0;` means = margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:30px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px. It's just a faster way of coding margin-top and margin-bottom if they are the same value.

Comment: @manouna I see that the result is not what you want. Please try creating a jsfiddle or a codepen and copy paste my code (from the codepen https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/mdPGzdm) and then just change the values with your values. Tell me if that works.

Comment: Also, if my answer helped you with your issue, please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Thank you