# Buttons not spaced

Tags: html, css, web

For some reason, on a webpage, my buttons are not spaced while I clearly put a margin. could anyone help ?

CSS for the buttons:

```
.sidebar button {
            margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px; /* marge de 30px entre les boutons */
            max-width: 100px; 
  }
```

Image of the outcome:

[image]

*This isn't a replica of my old question, as has been reported by someone. This one is solely about buttons tyling not appearing while the oter one was about aligning an iframe and a sidebar on the same line.

FULL CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MaThé</title>


    <!--By manouna-->
<!--font-->

  <style>

      * { padding: 0; margin: 0;}

      

      body {
          background-color: #E2EBDF;
          overflow-x: hidden;

      }

      @font-face {
          font-family: 'Champagne & Limousines';
          src: url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.eot');
          src: url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.woff2') format('woff2'),
               url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.woff') format('woff'),
               url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.ttf') format('truetype'),
               url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.svg#Champagne & Limousines') format('svg'),
               url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');

        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
  }

      .bigtxt {
          font-size: 100px;
          font-family: 'Champagne & Limousines';
          color: inherit;
      }

      .normaltext {
          font-family: Baskerville,Baskerville Old Face,Hoefler Text,Garamond,Times New Roman,serif; 
      }


      /*CSS du iframe et du sidebar*/

      
      .container img {   /*bannière*/
            width: 100%;
            max-height: 250px;
      }

      .bigtxt {
            font-size: 70px;
      }

      .flex-container {  /* flex pour le layout (iframe) */
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0px;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
      }

       .sidebar { /* aussi flex, mais flex-direction: column; pour que les boutons soient verticaux*/
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 710px;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 30%; /*réserver l'autre 70% du container au iframe*/
            align-items: center; /*Boutons*/
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            align-content: space-around;
            
            

       .sidebar button {
            margin: 30px; /* marge de 30px entre les boutons */
            width: 60px;
            height: 20px;
            max-height: 20px !important;
            max-width: 60px !important; 
            background-color: #F5FAD2;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 24px;
            display: block;

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'Champagne & Limousines';
                  src: url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.eot');
                  src: url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.woff2') format('woff2'),
                  url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.woff') format('woff'),
                  url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.ttf') format('truetype'),
                  url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.svg#Champagne & Limousines') format('svg'),
                  url('/fonts/Champagne & Limousines.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');

                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
            
      }
   
       iframe {

            width: 70%;  /* le iframe prendra 70% du 100% de la largeur du .flexbox container */
            
      }

  </style>


</head>

<body>



    <div class="container">
        <img src="images/bannersite.png" alt="Banner" style="width:100%;">
        
        <div class="bigtxt" style="left: 100px; top: 70px; position: absolute;">
            <span style="color: #B3D1B3;">Ma</span><span style="color: #404040;">Thé</span>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="flex-container"> <!-- la sidebar et le iframe seront dedans -->
       
        <div class="sidebar">
            <button class="sidebar" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">Button</button>

            <button class="sidebar" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">Button</button> 

            <button class="sidebar" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">Button</button>
        </div>
        
        <iframe src="accueil.html" frameborder="0" style="border: none; width: inherit; height: 710px;">
        </iframe>

    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. Your code should work as-is unless there is a style in `.sidebar` that is overwriting it. Can you confirm that your buttons are getting the margin applied to them with an inspector? It would help if could share your HTML too as well as the CSS for `.sidebar`.

Comment: They are spaced. You put margins on the top and bottom. Not on the left or right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Put an iframe on the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63944727/put-an-iframe-on-the-right)

Comment: @mamouna this question is a 100% duplicate of your queston https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63944727 I have flagged it and reported it to the moderators. You should not open more than one question for the same issue. Thank you

Comment: .sidebar button {display: inline-block}

Answer (score 0):

If you have put the 3 button in the div and you have given height to that div
Then as the height is fixed earlier so it is not able to make extra space
Check every div where you may have given some height which is restricting it from getting extra space

Comment: That's not correct. The buttons will overflow the container.  See example below

Answer (score 0):

Can you better describe the problem?  The code here seems to be fine.

```css
.sidebar button {
            margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px; /* marge de 30px entre les boutons */
            max-width: 100px; 
            display:block;
  }
  
  .sidebar{
  height:100px;
  background-color:lightgrey;
  }
```

```html
<div class='sidebar'>
<button>button</button>
<button>button</button>
<button>button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: nothing is working... my sidebar code :

 .sidebar { 

            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 710px;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 30%; /*réserver l'autre 30% du container au iframe*/
            align-items: center; /*Boutons*/
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            align-content: space-around;

Comment: provide complete html and css